# Text widget overflow options don't appear to work

Tags: flutter

I have a Text widget which is overflowing its box.  I've experimented with the various overflow options but they don't seem to make any difference.

[image]

Any thoughts what I'm doing wrong?

```
 @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ListView.separated(
        separatorBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
          return SizedBox(height: 7);
        },
        padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(10.0, 4.0, 10.0, 4.0),
        itemCount: items.length,
        itemBuilder: (context, index) {
          final item = items[index];

          return Card(
              shadowColor: Colors.blueAccent,
              elevation: 5,
              shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15.0),
              ),
              color: Color(0xfffffbe7),   
              child: Container(
                padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(16.0, 4.0, 16.0, 4.0),
                child: Column(
                  children: [
                    ...
                    Row(
                      children: [
                        Text(  **// <<<< This is the overflowing widget**
                          '${item.name}',  
                          maxLines: 1,
                          overflow: TextOverflow.clip,
                          style: TextStyle(
                              fontFamily: 'Montserrat',
                              fontSize: 18.0,
                              fontWeight: FontWeight.normal,
                              color: Colors.blue),
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
```

Comment: Does making the Column crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch works for you? It seems that you are not limiting the width. Also, the Text inside the Row should be in a Expanded widget.

Comment: @LeonardoSilva Sorry, that doesn't seem to make any difference.

Comment: this kind of overflow happens when the text does not know what size it should be. if it is not what I mentioned it could be other thing. but just for testing, put the Text inside a SizedBox with defined width, the overflow will work, but this is not the solution. A column with the default crossAxisAlignment does not define a width, and an element inside a row without being flex (Expanded) does not define width also.

Comment: @LeonardoSilva You're right.  Putting it inside a SizedBox with a fixed width makes it handle overflow correctly (apart from "fade", which fades from top to bottom, not to the right.) The ListView is inside a Scaffold( Stack( Flex( Expanded( AnimatedSwitcher(...))))).  I think you're suggesting that one of those might be the culprit?

Comment: put a container with some color outside of the column and see if it occupies the whole width, if it does, than the problem is below it, if it does not, it is above it. do it to every element until u find the one that is not growing to full width, then the fix will depend on the widget.

Comment: @LeonardoSilva Do you mean the Container() that's already there outside the Column()?  Adding a color argument to that colors the exact width of the card, shown in cream in the above image.

Comment: then I can only think of what I said in the first comment, that is the most obvious by the code and the output, add the CrossAxisAlignment.stretch to the Column, to limit the Row width and make the Text inside the Row be Expanded, to limit the Text width, or if it is the only child of the row, remove the Row. These 2 changes are required by what I can see.

Comment: @LeonardoSilva  Removing the Row() wrapping the solitary Text() widget got the overflow working correctly, though the text was centered rather than left justified.  Adding crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch to the Column() made it left justified again.  Many thanks for that, though I must admit I'm at a bit of a loss to understand what was broken here and why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The overflow of a Text widget will only work if the Text has a defined width.

There are two problems in the code provided:

- The Text is inside a Row, that does not constrain the width of the children if they are not Flex.
- The Column does not give a minimum width for the children in the default crossAxisAligment.

Making the crossAxisAligment of the Column be CrossAxisAlignment.stretch, make it expand the width of all children to match the available space for the Column. This still leaves the Row problem.

To solve the Row problem, you can define the width of the Text explicitily using a SizedBox, or you can use Flex. Expanded is a Flex widget that makes the child expand to fill the available space, so it works here.
But in the example, since the Text is the only child of the Row, removing the Row widget solves the Row problem.

If only the Row problem is solved, Texts that are smaller than the width of the Column will be centered, while the others will follow the TextDirection.

Answer (score 0):

Try wrapping your Text with `Flexible()`

```
                Row(
                  children: [
                    Flexible( //Add flexible here
                      child:Text('${item.name}',
                      maxLines: 1,
                      overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                      style: TextStyle(
                          fontFamily: 'Montserrat',
                          fontSize: 18.0,
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.normal,
                          color: Colors.blue),
                    )),
                  ],
                ),
```